# KSQL How to join a sensor data topic with an indicator topic without common id

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have data streaming into my topics from a sensor server, that i cannot control.

In Topic A there are multiple payloads of sensor data coming in (a,b,c,d...).

In Topic B there are indicator messages coming in (like 1,2,..), telling me that from now on incoming sensor data from topic A is belonging to the new object x instead of x-1

I want to join the the data from Topic A corresponding to the at that time current object from Topic B.

Im pretty new to KSQL and streaming logic so i do not know if this is possible. It feels like there could be a pretty simple solution but I did not find anything like this in the examples.

EDIT:

sensor data (topic A) could look like this:

```
sensorPath                        timestamp  value
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 1 |        7.0
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 1 |        2.0
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 2 |        6.0
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 2 |        1.0
...
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 10 |       10.0
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 10 |       12.0
```

indicator data (topic B) could look like this

```
informationPath                timestamp   WorkpieceID
simulation/informationString | 1  |        0020181
simulation/informationString | 10 |        0020182
```

I basically want to match the sensor data to the corresponding workpiece in a new topic/stream. New arriving sensor data always belongs to the newest informationString / workpiece.

So topic C should look like :

```
sensorPath                        SensorTimestamp  value WorkpieceID
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 1 |              7.0 | 0020181
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 1 |              2.0 | 0020181             
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 2 |              6.0 | 0020181
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 2 |              1.0 | 0020181
...
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 10 |             10.0| 0020182
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 10 |             12.0| 0020182
```

So i would need something like a join on topicA.timestamp >= current(topicB.timestamp) ?!

Comment: Hi @jmundorf! Can you update your question to include a sample of the message data? It's hard to visualise what you're trying to achieve from your description alone. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @RobinMoffatt ! I have added a simplified sample of the message data. I hope it helps understand my intentions.

Comment: I've posted an answer. I'd be interested to know more about your data source and use case - if you're open to discussing it you can email me robin@confluent.io. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with KSQL. Here's a worked example. I'm using [this docker-compose file](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/cos/docker-compose.yml) here for my test environment, if you want to reproduce the example below.

First, I'm populating some test data, based on the sample that you provided. I've made up the timestamps based on the current epoch, +2 and +10 seconds:

- sensor test data:

  ```
  docker run --rm --interactive --network cos_default confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -t sensor -P <<EOF
  {"sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","value":7.0,"timestamp":1541623171000}
  {"sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","value":2.0,"timestamp":1541623171000}
  {"sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","value":6.0,"timestamp":1541623231000}
  {"sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","value":1.0,"timestamp":1541623231000}
  {"sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","value":10.0,"timestamp":1541623771000}
  {"sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","value":12.0,"timestamp":1541623771000}
  EOF
  ```
- indicator test data:

  ```
  docker run --rm --interactive --network cos_default confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -t indicator -P << EOF
  {"informationPath":"simulation/informationString","WorkpieceID":"0020181","timestamp":1541623171000}
  {"informationPath":"simulation/informationString","WorkpieceID":"0020182","timestamp":1541623771000}
  EOF
  ```

Now, I launch the KSQL CLI:

```
docker run --network cos_default --interactive --tty --rm \
    confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.0.0 \
    http://ksql-server:8088
```

In KSQL we can examine the source data in the topic:

```
KSQL> PRINT 'sensor' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1541624847072,"ROWKEY":"null","sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","value":7.0,"timestamp":1541623171000}
{"ROWTIME":1541624847072,"ROWKEY":"null","sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","value":2.0,"timestamp":1541623171000}
{"ROWTIME":1541624847072,"ROWKEY":"null","sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","value":6.0,"timestamp":1541623231000}
{"ROWTIME":1541624847072,"ROWKEY":"null","sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","value":1.0,"timestamp":1541623231000}
{"ROWTIME":1541624847072,"ROWKEY":"null","sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","value":10.0,"timestamp":1541623771000}
{"ROWTIME":1541624847072,"ROWKEY":"null","sensorPath":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","value":12.0,"timestamp":1541623771000}

KSQL> PRINT 'indicator' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1541624851692,"ROWKEY":"null","informationPath":"simulation/informationString","WorkpieceID":"0020181","timestamp":1541623171000}
{"ROWTIME":1541624851692,"ROWKEY":"null","informationPath":"simulation/informationString","WorkpieceID":"0020182","timestamp":1541623771000}
```

Now we register the topic for use in KSQL, and declare the schema:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM SENSOR (SENSORPATH VARCHAR, VALUE DOUBLE, TIMESTAMP BIGINT) WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',KAFKA_TOPIC='sensor',TIMESTAMP='timestamp');

Message
----------------
Stream created
----------------
ksql> CREATE STREAM INDICATOR (INFORMATIONPATH VARCHAR, WORKPIECEID VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP BIGINT) WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',KAFKA_TOPIC='indicator',TIMESTAMP='timestamp');

Message
----------------
Stream created
----------------
```

We can query the KSQL streams that have been created:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
ksql> SELECT ROWTIME, timestamp, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'), TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z') , sensorpath, value FROM sensor;
1541623171000 | 1541623171000 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 7.0
1541623171000 | 1541623171000 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 2.0
1541623231000 | 1541623231000 | 2018-11-07 20:40:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:40:31 +0000 | simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 6.0
1541623231000 | 1541623231000 | 2018-11-07 20:40:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:40:31 +0000 | simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 1.0
1541623771000 | 1541623771000 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 10.0
1541623771000 | 1541623771000 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 12.0

ksql> SELECT ROWTIME, timestamp, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'), TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z') , informationPath, WorkpieceID FROM indicator;
1541623171000 | 1541623171000 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | simulation/informationString | 0020181
1541623771000 | 1541623771000 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | simulation/informationString | 0020182
```

Note that `ROWTIME` of the STREAM is different from `ROWTIME` in the `PRINT` output. That's because the `PRINT` output shows the Kafka message timestamp, whereas in the STREAM we overrode the timestamp in the `WITH` clause to instead use the `timestamp` column from the message payload itself.

To join between the two topics, we're going to two do things:

1. Create an artificial key on which to join them, since none exists in the data currently. We'll also apply this new column as the key of the Kafka message (which is necessary for the join to take place).
2. Model the 'indicator' event stream as a KSQL *table*. This enables us query the *current state* of the `WorkpieceID` value based on the timestamp

To add in an artificial join key simply select a constant and alias it with the `AS` clause, and use it as the message key with `PARTITION BY`:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM SENSOR_KEYED AS SELECT sensorPath, value, 'X' AS JOIN_KEY FROM sensor PARTITION BY JOIN_KEY;

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
```

For interest, we can inspect the resulting Kafka topic that's been created

```
ksql> PRINT SENSOR_KEYED FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1541623171000,"ROWKEY":"X","SENSORPATH":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","VALUE":7.0,"JOIN_KEY":"X"}
{"ROWTIME":1541623171000,"ROWKEY":"X","SENSORPATH":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","VALUE":2.0,"JOIN_KEY":"X"}
{"ROWTIME":1541623231000,"ROWKEY":"X","SENSORPATH":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","VALUE":6.0,"JOIN_KEY":"X"}
{"ROWTIME":1541623231000,"ROWKEY":"X","SENSORPATH":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","VALUE":1.0,"JOIN_KEY":"X"}
{"ROWTIME":1541623771000,"ROWKEY":"X","SENSORPATH":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1","VALUE":10.0,"JOIN_KEY":"X"}
{"ROWTIME":1541623771000,"ROWKEY":"X","SENSORPATH":"simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2","VALUE":12.0,"JOIN_KEY":"X"}
```

Note that ROWKEY is now the JOIN_KEY, instead of NULL as above in the `PRINT 'sensor'` output. If you omit the `PARTITION BY` then the JOIN_KEY is added but the messages remain un-keyed, which is not what we want for the join to be able to work.

Now we re-key the indicator data too:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM INDICATOR_KEYED AS SELECT informationPath, WorkpieceID, 'X' as JOIN_KEY FROM indicator PARTITION BY JOIN_KEY;

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql> PRINT 'INDICATOR_KEYED' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1541623171000,"ROWKEY":"X","INFORMATIONPATH":"simulation/informationString","WORKPIECEID":"0020181","JOIN_KEY":"X"}
{"ROWTIME":1541623771000,"ROWKEY":"X","INFORMATIONPATH":"simulation/informationString","WORKPIECEID":"0020182","JOIN_KEY":"X"}
```

Having rekeyed the indicator data, we can now register it as a KSQL table. In a table the *state of the key* is returned by KSQL, instead of *every event*. We're using this approach to determine the `WorkpieceID` to associate with the sensor reading, based on the  timestamp.

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE INDICATOR_STATE (JOIN_KEY VARCHAR, informationPath varchar, WorkpieceID varchar) with (value_format='json',kafka_topic='INDICATOR_KEYED',KEY='JOIN_KEY');

Message
---------------
Table created
---------------
```

Querying the table shows a single value, which is the *current* state:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM INDICATOR_STATE;
1541623771000 | X | X | simulation/informationString | 0020182
```

If at this point you sent another message to the `indicator` topic, the state of the table would update and you'd see a new row emitted from the `SELECT`.

Finally, we can do a stream-table join, persisted to a new topic:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM SENSOR_ENRICHED AS SELECT S.SENSORPATH, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(S.ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z') AS SENSOR_TIMESTAMP, S.VALUE, I.WORKPIECEID FROM SENSOR_KEYED S LEFT JOIN INDICATOR_STATE I ON S.JOIN_KEY=I.JOIN_KEY;

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
```

Examine the new stream:

```
ksql> DESCRIBE SENSOR_ENRICHED;

Name                 : SENSOR_ENRICHED
Field            | Type
----------------------------------------------
ROWTIME          | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY           | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
SENSORPATH       | VARCHAR(STRING)
SENSOR_TIMESTAMP | VARCHAR(STRING)
VALUE            | DOUBLE
WORKPIECEID      | VARCHAR(STRING)
----------------------------------------------
For runtime statistics and query details run: DESCRIBE EXTENDED <Stream,Table>;
```

Query the new stream:

```
ksql> SELECT SENSORPATH, SENSOR_TIMESTAMP, VALUE, WORKPIECEID FROM SENSOR_ENRICHED;
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | 7.0 | 0020181
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 2018-11-07 20:39:31 +0000 | 2.0 | 0020181
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 2018-11-07 20:40:31 +0000 | 6.0 | 0020181
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 2018-11-07 20:40:31 +0000 | 1.0 | 0020181
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-1 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | 10.0 | 0020182
simulation/machine/plc/sensor-2 | 2018-11-07 20:49:31 +0000 | 12.0 | 0020182
```

Since this is KSQL, the `SENSOR_ENRICHED` stream (and underlying topic of the same name) will be continually populated, driven by events arriving on the `sensor` topic and reflecting any state change based on events sent to `indicator` topic.